# Fastapi - response model exclude

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I have one response model which I use for two fast api end points. The second end point is very similar the first one, but I would like to remove one response parameter from it.

It looks like this:

endpoints:

```
app = FastAPI(title = settings.TITLE,
version=settings.VERSION,
description=settings.DESCRIPTION,
contact=settings.CONTACT
)

@app.get("/EP1", response_model=Model)
async def Func1():
    ...

@app.get("/EP2", response_model=Model)
async def Func2():
    ...
```

Model looks like this:

```
class ResourceInformation(BaseModel):
    resource_id:Optional[str]
    resource_pricing:Optional[list[PricingInformation]]
    has_backup:Optional[bool] = None

class InvoicingInformation(BaseModel):
    ...
    resource_information:Optional[list[ResourceInformation]] = None
    ...

class Model(BaseModel):
    data:Optional[list[InvoicingInformation]]
```

What I would like to achieve is hiding each occurence of "has_backup" in response of EP2.

Comment: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#use-the-response_model_exclude_unset-parameter, https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#response_model_include-and-response_model_exclude

Comment: just implement two versions of the ResourceInformation model, one that inherits the first but with has_backup added and use the one needed accordingly?

Comment: Think of it as `EP1` _adding_ `has_backup` instead of as `EP2` _removing_ `has_backup`.

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide
Yeah, that has done the work. thanks :)